# Jquery Datatables: Load Data with Ajax call

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am trying to load data in datatable with ajax call response. I am getting

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Please review my code and guide

HTML:

```
<table id="listing_task_logs" class="table custom-table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Date Added</th>
    <th>Task Date</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Staff</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> 
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#listing_task_logs').DataTable({
        "searching": false,
        "bLengthChange" : false,

        "ajax": "/listing/1761401/get_all_tasks",
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "date_added" },
                    { "data": "time" },
                    { "data": "status.status_title" },
                    { "data": "todo" },
                    { "data": "comments" }
                ],
        "dataSrc":"",
    });
});
```

Ajax Response:

> [{    "task_id": 320,     "listing_id": 1761401,  "time": "0000-00-00
>   00:00:00",    "comments": "zxc",  "date_added": "2019-08-22 12:32:38",
>     "next_status_id": 3,    "status": {         "status_id": 2,         "status_title":
>   "Property Visit"  },  "next_status": {        "status_id": 3,
>         "status_title": "MOU Meeting"   } }]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a property called `time` in your data. Remove `{ "data": "todo" },` and `<th>Staff</th>`, or change `"todo"` to property you actually want.